# Programmatically changing the language within the Android app using string resources?

Tags: java, android

I am relatively new to Android and want to know how to change the language of my app on the click of a button? I have extracted all the text and stored was string resources and set up new string resource files for each of the languages. My problem is around the `mainActivity.java` class.

Comment: Normally the user does it by setting the phone's locale.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android

Answer (score 0):

There is a library for the behaviour you want.
It is called the [localization library](https://github.com/akexorcist/Android-LocalizationActivity).
You have to extend the libraries LocalizationActivity.
You can than use setLanguage("en"); to change the language of your application at runtime. There is also a sample project available on the libraries GitHub page.